# Why does my ouput repeate Walt Disney 2 times when it should be the last one

Tags: java, computer-science

I have to display the distributors with the highest gross earnings and the lowest gross earnings. This is my code and it displays the lowest but it is displaying Walt Disney two times then gives the right answer on the 3rd one. How do I fix this?

I have tried putting the print outside of the loop and it repeats over 10 times and outside of the loop loop and it gives me an error.

```
public void GEarnings (String [] d, int [] g){ 
    int high = 0;
    int low = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index < g.length; index++){
        if(d[index].equals("Walt Disney"))   {
            high += g[index]; 
            System.out.println("Highest Earnings - " + d[index] + " " + "$" + df.format(high));
        }
    }

    for(int index = 0; index < g.length; index++){
        if(d[index].equals("20th Century Fox")){
            low += g[index];         
            System.out.println("Lowest Earnings - " + d[index] + " " + "$" + df.format(low));
        } 
    }   


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu6Ox.png)

Comment: it seems that you are not actually comparing the earnings at any point.

Comment: Can you provide the input to that function?

Comment: Can you provide an example output with a known inputs? And what you expect the output *should* be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show that the values you have are sorted in an incorrect way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GEarnings(String[] d, int[] g) {
    int high = 0;
    int low = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
        if(g[i] > g[high]) high = i;
        if(g[i] < g[low]) low = i;
    }

    System.out.println("Highest earnings - " + d[high] +", lowest earnings - " + d[low]);
}
```

For each earning `g[i]`, if it is higher than the one which index is stored in `high`, replace it. Same for `low`, if it is lower, we replace it.

We store the index `i` in `high` and `low` so we can get the name of the companies by searching `d[high]` and `d[low]`.

**Note**: It would be better to use a `Map<String, Integer>` to correctly link the companies and their earnings.

Comment: So the answer should be
Highest Earnings - Walt Disney $916,003,182
Lowest Earnings - 20th Century Fox $85,657,794
  but I am getting Paramount Pictures for the lowest and not the correct gross earnings.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `d` and `g` ?